# Why does we quantize fields $\phi(t,x)$ and not $\phi$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

In classical mechanics, the action of a theory is determined by its Lagrangian:
$$S(q) := \int L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)dt $$
In the following, let us assume that $L$ does not depend explicitly on time. Note that the Lagrangian is a function $L: \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. The Legendre transform of $L$ is the Hamiltonian:
$$H(q,p) = p\dot{q} - L(q,\dot{q}).$$
Again, $H$ is a function $H: \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$.

When we quantize a Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics, we usually take the expression for the classical $H$ and turn it into an operator $\hat{H}$ by replacing $x \mapsto \hat{x}$ the multiplication operator by $x$ and $p \mapsto \hat{p} := -i\nabla$.

In quantum field theory, this is done analogously. The Hamiltonian in this case is a function $H(\phi,\pi)$ of functions $\phi$ and $\pi$, defined as the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian:
$$H(\phi,\pi) = \int d^{3}x[\pi(x)\dot{\phi}(x)-\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\dot{\phi})]$$

Since now $H$ is a function of functions, why don't we quantize the functions $\phi$ and $\pi$ instead of fields (functions evaluated at points) $\phi(t,x)$ and $\pi(t,x)$? In quantum mechanics, time does not play any role and we do not quantize $q(t)$ and $p(t)$, but instead we quantize $q$ and $p$ because $H$ is a function of these variables. Shouldn't we do the same in the case of a classical field?

Comment: To clarify, are you under the impression that $\phi(t,x)$ is called a field and $\phi$ is called a function?

Comment: @J.Murray No, it just that the procedure is to quantize the function evaluated at points instead of the function itself.

Comment: Hint: Look up equal-time commutators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system with a *finite number* $f$ of degrees of freedom is quantized by imposing the canonical equal-time commutation relations ($\hbar=1$)$$\left[q_k(t),p_\ell(t)\right]=i\delta_{k\ell}, \quad \left[q_k(t),q_\ell(t)\right]=\left[p_k(t),p_\ell(t)\right]=0, \quad  1\leq k,\ell \leq f.$$ In the case of a field theory, the discrete index $k$ is replaced by the *continuous* variable $\vec{x}$ with the correspondence $$k \to \vec{x}, \quad q_k(t) \to \phi(t,\vec{x}), \quad p_k(t) \to \pi(t,\vec{x}). $$ A (bosonic) field theory is quantized by imposing the canonical equal-time commutation relations $$\left[\phi(t, \vec{x}),\pi(t, \vec{y})\right]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y}), \quad \left[\phi(t,\vec{x}), \phi(t,\vec{y})\right]=\left[\pi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})\right]=0.$$ In this respect, there is no conceptual difference between the quantization of a system with a finite number of degrees and a field theory with infinitely many degrees of freedom.